# Delay a user defined helper method with delayed_job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

So i have many database operations that i put into my helpers that i want to do in the background. As an example, I define a record_activity method in my Users helper. When a Post gets created I want to record this activity ie in the create method in the Posts controller:

```
 def create
     #operations to save the post
     record_activity(user, post)
 end
```

For performance reasons, I want to delay this record_activity and others, and run them with workers on the back-end. I use delayed_job for delaying mailers and it works excellently. In rails console, method.delay works great ie I could in rails console do:

```
 record_activity.delay
```

However, the same .delay doesn't work when written in a controller ie the following still runs live, not delayed:

```
 def create
     #operations to save the post
     record_activity(user, post).delay
 end
```

Why is this? I'm using Rails 3.0.9 in one app and Rails 3.1.3 in another, plus I have delayed_job version 2.1.4.

Can anyone suggest how to make this work?

EDIT ***

I think the answer provided by mu_is_too_short is the right path. It creates a delayed job, only it doesn't execute the record_activity method properly. When the delayed_job worker starts, it executes the delayed_job and has no errors, and deletes the record as if it worked. But no activity gets recorded. To give some context, here is the call and the method i am troubleshooting now:

```
self.delay.record_activity(user, @comment)
```

ANd the method:

```
def record_activity(current_user, act)
   activity = Activity.new
   activity.user_id = current_user.id
   activity.act_id = act.id
   activity.act_type = act.class.name
   activity.created_at = act.created_at
   activity.save
end
```

I then thought that maybe I couldn't pass user variables through, in this case, so I tried to just pass integer values and so on. I restarted the delayed_job workers and tried these methods, to no avail:

```
    self.delay.record_activity(user.id, @comment.id, @comment.class.name, @comment.created_at)
```

And the altered method:

```
   def record_activity(current_user_id, act_id, act_type, act_created_at)
     activity = Activity.new
     activity.user_id = current_user_id
     activity.act_id = act_id
     activity.act_type = act_type
     activity.created_at = act_created_at
     activity.save
   end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think `record_activity.delay` in the console is working the way you think it is. That will execute `record_activity` *before* `delay` has a chance to do anything.

The `delay` call has to go first, then you call your delayed method on what `delay` returns:

```
def create
    self.delay.record_activity(user, post)
end
```

The `delay` call will return an object that intercepts all method calls (probably through `method_missing`), YAMLizes them, and adds the YAML to its delayed job queue table in the database. So, just saying `record_activity.delay` doesn't do anything useful, it just executes `record_activity`, creates the delayed-job interceptor object, and throws away what `delay` created.

Comment: hmm this looks pretty good, and creates a delayed job. However, when it executes, it doesn't complete record_activity properly (ie no activity record gets created)- but doesn't produce any errors either, so the job disappears from the delayed_jobs table. What are the limitations to delaying jobs? Any advice here? Is the problem the delay call here?

Comment: @jay: Have you restarted your delayed-job workers? They don't auto-reload anything. What does `record_activity` look like? Does it work properly without the `delay` call?

Comment: have restarted to test. will add record_activity to the question (as well as variations I have tested).

Comment: Oh and yes it works excellently without the delay call. Edits to my question have more info on the methods.

Comment: @jay: Hmmm. Is your delayed-job worker connecting to the right database? Maybe add some `Rails.logger` calls to watch what's going on and to see what `activity.save` does, switching to `activity.save!` might be useful as well.

Comment: ok, will check it out. have you ever used self.delay.method_name(vars) to delay a user defined method? just wondering if it is necessarily a problem on how I am writing the method

Comment: @jay: Yes, I do it all the time.

Comment: In your experience, can you pass whole objects (current_user) in this case? Are there advantages to, say, passing the object vs, say,  passing the object id? (Answer is yours -- thanks!!)

Comment: I tend to pass just IDs so that I don't have to worry non-serializable arguments (which is quite rare). Almost all of my delayed methods are only called through delayed-job so I know that they'll be reloaded from the database anyway so why not do it by hand?

Comment: yeah, seems like the right idea. i'll try to wrtie a logger etc and find my error, thanks for all the help though!

Comment: hey, it's been a while, but I still have issues. If you have a moment, please check out this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9695440/delayed-job-wont-alter-database-for-user-defined-method